# How to restrict mongoose default value whose not present in database during find()

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  test: {
    type: String, 
    default: 'hello world'
  }
});

UserSchema.pre('save', function(callback) {
  var user = this;
  this.test = undefined; // here unset test field which prevent to add in db 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

But when I find data for example

```
User.find(function(err, users) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);

    res.json(users);
  });
```

it always returns

```
[
    {
        _id: "56fa6c15a9383e7c0f2e4477",
        username: "abca",
        password: "$2a$05$GkssfHjoZnX8na/QMe79LOwutun1bv2o76gTQsIThnjOTW.sobD/2",
        __v: 0,
        test: "hello world"
    }
]
```

How can I modify or add any special param to get data without `test` field and without any change in query, let's say

```
User.find({}, '-test', function (err, users){

});
```

also, I have set the default value in model: `test: "hello world"`
but I do not want this value to appear in the response.
I have also set `this.test = undefined;` and this should mean that it is preventing this default value to be added into database, however I am still getting this in response.

Answer (score 2):

1. You want the `test` property persisted in database and just don't want it selected when querying:

You can use `select` in a pre find hook:

```
UserSchema.pre('find', function (next) {
    this.select({ test: false });
    next();
});
```

In a query hook (as opposed to a save hook for example), `this` refers to your query object. In a save hook it refers to the current document being saved.

This hook will only execute for `find` queries, not `findById` or `findOne` queries.

OR

(see Hank Chiu's answer)

set the select flag to false in the schema :

```
test: {
      type: String, 
      default: 'hello world',
      select: false,
}
```

2. You don't want the `test`property persisted in database :

Remove the `test` property from schema and add a `test` virtual :

```
schema.virtual('test').get(function () {
    return 'hello world';
});
```

`user.test` will return `hello world`.

3. You want the test property persisted in database but return something different :

Add a `getter` your `test` definition :

```
test: {
    type: String, 
    default: 'hello world',
    get: function () {
        return 'hello guys';
    }
}
```

`user.test` will return `hello guys` but its true value will be persisted in database.

Old erroneous answer :

<strike>You can use `select` which takes an object of Model properties as keys and booleans as values :</strike>

```
User
    .find({})
    .select({
        test: false;
    })
    .exec(function (err, users) {
        // users won't have the test property
    });
```

Comment: That is exactly the same as what `'-test'` does. So that's not what the OP is asking. They want the field exluded "automatically" so that **every** `.find()` call already excludes the field without having to do `'-test'` or `.select({ "test": false })` or `.select({ "test": -1 })` ( which is again the same thing )

Comment: Oh you're right. I missed the "without any change in query" part, my bad. I updated my answer

Comment: Probably should note that [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) like this is pretty specific. So you would need `findOne` as well or else a `.findOne()` or `.findById()` would "still" return the field. I also wonder if considering the OP does not want to "store" the data if "virtuals" would be a better choice, and then excluding them from serialization. That can be done as well.

Comment: I agree, there's many ways to exclude a field from query results, but it all comes down to what the OP needs. I think that a find middleware makes sense if he wants to exclude fields from a generic query to make the results lighter. If he's querying a specific user, I think he's more likely to want to include all fields.

I edited my answer based on your comment.

Comment: Thanks  both of you  for your quick response and very informative answer  :) , actually I have multiple user roles "instructor", "client" , " admin" and "studio"  . Each role  has similar and different fields . So, I want to add only desired field associated to particular role and  exclude remaining ones.

Comment: You might want to lookup discriminators for that : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html.
It will allow you to define models that inherits from another schema. This way you can define an admin schema that inherits from user schema.

Comment: I look into link provided by you . Here I face another issue . As, discrminator schema was based which inherited by child schema . 
Events -> ClickedLink. If we create 5 collections like 
1)user -> instructor 
2)user-> student 
3)user-> studio
4)user-> admin
5) user it self
It better to create 4 different collections with full fields rather than inherit 
1) student 
2) instructor
3) studio
4) admin

Comment: Please open a new question, as it is a different matter :)

Answer (score 2):

Set your schema as

```
test: {
    type: String, 
    default: 'hello world',
    select: false
}
```

Check the [SchemaType#select](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-select) in the [document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype-js).

Comment: Thank you for answer, Can I define "select" on conditional basis ?

Comment: What do you mean "on conditional basis"? Once `select:false` defined, you can retrieve the attribute by using `select('+test')` when query.

Comment: I have multiple roles like student, instructor, studio . So, what can I do to make "select"  true for student  and false for instructor?

Comment: You can use function in `default` attribute, ex. `default: function(){ return (this.role=='student') ? 'hello world':'';}`. But this will not work if you are going to store different values in the field `test`.

Comment: Chui , I understand your logic but problem is  if role is "student" then default value become 'hello world' when role become "instructor" or else  it's become '' (empty string ) still test field  save in db . When I find any roles lets say "Instructor " field become visible for example  "test: ' ' "

Answer (score 0):

Use `select` function as your example it would be like

```
User.find(/* condition */).select('username -_id -__v')
```

The above code will return the `username` field only

**TL: DR**

Fields are written as a single string with whitespace separator, to exclude field add `-` prefix like `-_id` or `-username`.